# How to create copy trigger function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE order (
  id             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  total_price    DECIMAL(12, 2),
  date           TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now(),
  product_amount INT
);
```

And another table for order history

```
CREATE TABLE order_history (
  id             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  order_id       INT,
  total_price    DECIMAL(12, 2),
  date           TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now(),
  product_amount INT  
);
```

I need a trigger function for `ORDER` table which can trigger on event when I insert some data into `ORDER` table or update data. Moreover this procedure must persist data into table `ORDER_HISTORY`.

Comment: Here is a generic solution for this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION save_order_in_history()
  RETURNS trigger
AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO order_history(order_id, total_price, product_amount)
  VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.total_price, NEW.product_amount);
  RETURN NULL;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER order_trigger AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON "order" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE save_order_in_history();
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/71202/1)** demo

Further reading:

- [CREATE TRIGGER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtrigger.html)
- [Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)